# Overflow error in Instr()

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still trying to get some data out of a web page, I got a solution how to "grep" the HTML text but now I'm trying to separate some parts from this text which is in a string.

I want to take out a part which is between variable A and variable B and use the following code.

I always get a `Runtime error 6 Overflow`, does someone have an idea why and how I can fix this?

```
Sub Button1_Click()

   Const HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY = 2    
   Dim oRequest As Object, pagetext, third As String, first, second As Integer

   Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")    
   oRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.vodafone.de/privat/handys-tablets-tarife/smartphone-tarife.html"

   oRequest.Send    
   pagetext = oRequest.ResponseText    

   first = InStr(pagetext, "window.phones")
   second = InStr(first + 1, pagetext, "window.propositions")
   third = Mid(pagetext, first + 1, second - first - 1)

   MsgBox (third)

End Sub
```

Comment: it seems that your `third` variable is not dimensioned. If you stick `Option Explicit` as the first line of your module you can help yourself avoid a lot of runtime errors..

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does. `Dim oRequest As Object, pagetext, third As String, first, second As Integer`. PageText and first are being declared as variants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the declaration from `Integer` to `Long` for the `second` variable.

`Integer` type can hold numbers up to 32,767 and the value returned by the expression (*`154031`*) is greater than that. `Long` data type can hold numbers up to 2,147,483,647 so it's better suitable for your specific case.

Generally, VBA converts all `Integers` to `Long` these days so it's a better practice to dim your variables as `Long` by default.

Additionally, you should also be careful when dim'ing multiple variables in one line because

```
 Dim oRequest As Object, pagetext, third As String, first, second As Integer
```

`first` is a `Variant` and `second` is an `Integer`

It should rather be

```
Dim oRequest As Object, pagetext, third As String, first as Long, second As Long
```